# How do I use google's code prettify on a target element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pretty-print, prettify

I'm currently using the google prettify script prettyPrint. It functions properly, except that it only has the one function call to do the whole page:

```
prettyPrint();
```

Ideally I'd like a jquery wrapper that allows:

```
$("#myelem").prettyPrint();
```

However this would also suffice:

```
prettyPrint('myElem');
```

I have a lot of <pre> tags and initializing them all at the same time is overkill. how do I target a specific element with prettyPrint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a replacement: http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/ after reading this overflow: [How to write an HTML JSON AJAX test harness with prettify, syntax highlighted JSON result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165434/how-to-write-an-html-json-ajax-test-harness-with-prettify-syntax-highlighted-js?rq=1)